# BOOTSTRAP // not working despite adding cdn links and reference style link // PYTHON

Tags: python, html, django, twitter-bootstrap, cloud9

I'm currently in the middle of building this [Django app](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Forms) and after I got the main parts that I wanted which were the login page and the homepage working, I decided on updating the look of my page because it was VERY basic. I've used bootstrap a ton before and I'm in love with it. However, this problem to me is a first. As you will see down below I have linked bootstrap via CDN (TWICE) and also via reference stylesheet link. Despite all these different ways of getting bootstrap my page still looks like this

[image: my page still looks like this].

Here is my base_generic.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    {% block title %}<title>Local Library</title>{% endblock %}
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">-->
  <!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
  <!--<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>-->


    <!-- Add additional CSS in static file -->
    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}">
    <!--<img src="{% static 'catalog/images/local_library_model_uml.png' %}" alt="My image" style="width:555px;height:540px;"/>-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" />

</head>

<body>
    {% include "header.html" %}


    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
            {% block content %}{% endblock %}
            {% include "pagination.html" %}
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my header.html file that has my navbar

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Heres what my file structure looks like

[image: Framework]

Any input or feedback would be helpful really. I'm really stuck here.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to the `settings.py` file:

```py
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

putting this within the head tag, solved the problem for me.